# ExecuteNonQuery Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, executenonquery

I'm writing a small app that will be used to deploy stored procedure updates/releases across a  number of servers.

I need to report back that the update on each server was successful.

At present I'm simply doing the following:

```
int response =  server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
```

This successfully updates the sp, but the response is always a random minus number (-3, -4 etc).

What would be the best way to get a response to report back if each update was successful  or not?

Comment: Can you show the SQL?

Comment: It will simply be a "ALTER PROCEDURE ........."

Comment: Return Value
Type: System.Int32
An Int32 value that specifies the total number of rows affected by the Transact-SQL command for UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the best way to get a response to report back if each update was successful or not

if the query has executed successfully and you haven't caught any exception then it means it is a success. otherwise it failed.

Comment: Thanks for that. Assumed as much but didn't know if there was a better way I could actually get a success/fail response.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Transaction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) (if your sql command based on multiple table) along with Try-Catch in SQL by using [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx). You get get the error as output variable.